# How to redirect / route VPN traffic to back standing local network?

Tags: vpn, routing, lan, traffic, redirection

There are two computers one "HOME" with Ubuntu 10.10 installed, and another "WORK" with WinXP installed. WORK PC is behind draconian firewall. However, let's imagine, that there is VPN connection installed between this 2 work stations, for example, with teamviewer, hamachi, openvpn, or by some other mean (by the way, what is the best mean for such purposes?).

One is interested in working with WORK's LAN resources from his HOME computer via VPN. So my question is about configuration required to be done on WinXP machine (or, maybe on both machines), to make such interaction possible?

I'm guessing that some routing stuff should be performed somewhere. But I don't know what exactly and how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hamachi supports this out of the box.  You'll want to setup a Gateway Network:

> Provide secure access to your private
>   network/LAN, including the resources
>   on it, from a centralized LogMeIn
>   Hamachi² gateway, without modifying
>   firewalls or network routers.

You can configure the type of network you want from their control panel when you sign up.  Your work computer would be the Gateway.

This may violate your workplace computer use policies so just be aware of that.

Comment: thx for your reply, but unfortunately this couldn't be done, because WORK PC -- is a domain member: "_... The gateway computer cannot be a Windows workstation that is the member of a domain. You can change the gateway at any time._"

Comment: Bummer.  The extent of my experience is with Hamachi, maybe somebody else will come up with something better.  OpenVPN might be worth looking at, but in my case Hamachi did all I needed to solve a short term problem.

Comment: Just for information, [here](http://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/Gateway-machine-on-Domain/m-p/31413) is the explanation of such restriction: _"This is done for security purposes, as setting a gateway network establishes a Network Bridge between the LAN adapter and the Hamachi adapter, allowing access to Domain resources through Hamachi.  This is not something that should ever be outside of the control of the Domain administrators."_